# PHP: XPath query returns nothing from large XML

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
$newstring = substr_replace("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=", $_COOKIE["word"], 39, 0);
/*$curl = curl_init($newstring);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);*/
//echo $result;


$xml = simplexml_load_file($newstring);
//print_r($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$value = $xpath->query("//track/@href");

foreach ($value as $e) {
  echo $e->nodevalue;
}
```

This is my code. I am using spotify to supply me with an xml document. I am then trying to get the href link from all of the track tags so I can use it. Right now the print_r($xml) I have commented out works, but if I try to query and print that out it returns nothing. The exact link I am trying to get my xml from is: http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=incredible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe is not the answer you need, because I dropped the `DOMXPath`, I'm using `getElementsByTagName()` instead.

```
$url = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track?q=incredible";

$xml = file_get_contents( $url );
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML( $xml );

$value = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName( "track" );
foreach ( $value as $e ) {
    echo $e->getAttribute( "href" )."<br>";
}
```